# Accumulate multiple updates to rrd

Tags: time-series, rrdtool, rrd

My use case is that there are updates coming from multiple sources and i've to store sum of all updates. One way is that i create separate rrd files for each source and run a cron that stores sum to the aggregate rrd file.

I was wondering if there is a way (using rrdcached perhaps?) that all sources update to this single rrd file and all updates inside same step gets summed together and stored in rrd.

Please let me know if this is possible.

-- 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you could log to a single rrd file using the ABSOLUTE data source type ...

Comment: Do you mean DST? As there is no CF called ABSOLUTE. Also can you explain a bit how would that help. AFAIK ABSOLUTE is just like COUNTER except it is assumed that counter is reset everytime it is read.

Comment: nm. I got what you are saying. Thanks.